# Looking for Spanish varieties/accents

Tags: phonology, pronunciation, dialects, spanish, accent

This might not be the right place to ask this, and if so, I apologize. I'm a student conducting research on Spanish varieties and I am wondering if anyone knows where I could find short texts read by speakers of Spanish varieties, or if anyone knows of an online community that would be willing to help me out by providing recordings.

Comment: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=accents+in+spanish+speaking+countries) has a lot of videos covering comparisons of accents in Spanish.

Comment: Also [Acentos en Español](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=acentos+en+espanol)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! My problem with using YouTube is that most of the videos are an individual imitating accents, while I'm looking for individuals from different regions to speak the exact same text for research. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand now, that you want native speakers of each accent. I don't know of one for Spanish though I'd expect there to be one at some university hosted website. These are only comments because I don't know anything just giving hints on how to search for it.

Comment: [Here is such a site for English](https://www.dialectsarchive.com/). So now all we have to do is find that but for Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a map of European languages and words. When you roll over a word you'll hear it pronounced.

> [Sound Comparisons](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Romance/map/eight/Lgs_All)

I've pre-chosen the Romance family for you for the word 'eight'. Move around the map to find instances of varieties, or use the language chooser on the left.

Another useful resource is

> [Forvo](https://forvo.com).

Search for a word and then  you'll get a number of pronunciations. They are mostly attempts at a standard variety but they are no labeled as to which variety.

These are just single words. For longer repeated phrases just for Spanish varieties, see:

> [OSU Voices of the Hispanic World](http://dialectos.osu.edu/)

Their [advanced search](http://dialectos.osu.edu/advanced-search) is much easier to browse.

Comment: I'd prefer a Spanish site, and also one easier to navigate, but I think this is what you want.